# Disposable.Create async overload

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, disposable

I'm working on a message bus class library for Redis ([StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)) and NATS ([AlterNats](https://github.com/Cysharp/AlterNats)). The `SubscribeAsync` method uses observers from System.Reactive for the callbacks.

The problem is `_connection` in `NatsSubscriber` has only  DisposeAsync overload and I cannot really use async in `Disposable.Create` because it would become async void. What should I do?

```cs
public sealed class NatsSubscriber<TKey, TMessage> : IBusSubscriber<TKey, TMessage>
{
    private readonly NatsConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;

    public NatsSubscriber(NatsConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    public async Task<IDisposable> SubscribeAsync(TKey key, Action<TMessage> callback)
    {
        var subject = GetSubjectString(key);

        if (subject == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }

        var connection = await _connectionFactory.GetConnectionAsync();

        var observer = Observer.Create(callback);

        await connection.SubscribeAsync<TMessage>(subject, data =>
        {
            observer.OnNext(data);
        });

        return Disposable.Create(subject, _ =>
        {
            // await connection.DisposeAsync();
            observer.OnCompleted();
        });
    }

    private string? GetSubjectString(TKey key)
    {
        return key switch
        {
            NatsKey natsKey => natsKey.Key,
            string s => s,
            _ => key?.ToString()
        };
    }
}

public sealed class RedisSubscriber<TKey, TMessage> : IBusSubscriber<TKey, TMessage>
{
    private readonly IConnectionMultiplexer _connectionMultiplexer;
    private readonly IRedisSerializer _serializer;

    public RedisSubscriber(IConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer, IRedisSerializer serializer)
    {
        _connectionMultiplexer = connectionMultiplexer;
        _serializer = serializer;
    }

    public async Task<IDisposable> SubscribeAsync(TKey key, Action<TMessage> callback)
    {
        var channel = CreateChannel(key);
        var subscriber = _connectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber();
        var observer = Observer.Create(callback);

        await subscriber.SubscribeAsync(channel, (_, redisValue) =>
        {
            observer.OnNext(_serializer.Deserialize<TMessage>(redisValue.ToString()));
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Disposable.Create(channel, x =>
        {
            subscriber.Unsubscribe(x);
            observer.OnCompleted();
        });
    }

    private RedisChannel CreateChannel(TKey key)
    {
        return key switch
        {
            string s => new RedisChannel(s, RedisChannel.PatternMode.Auto),
            byte[] v => new RedisChannel(v, RedisChannel.PatternMode.Auto),
            _ => new RedisChannel(_serializer.Serialize(key), RedisChannel.PatternMode.Literal)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a [`Disposables` library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Disposables) that supports async disposables. However, that would require `SubscribeAsync` to return `IAsyncDisposable` instead of `IDisposable`.

Comment: You can create a `non-async` version of the Dispose method that calls `DisposeAsync` and waits for the task to complete

Comment: @StephenCleary that is okay as long as both RedisSubscriber and NatsSubscriber are using it. It would be nice to see your approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a [`Disposables` library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Disposables) that has full support for async disposables. This would require you to change `IBusSubscriber<TKey, TMessage>.SubscribeAsync` to return `Task<IAsyncDisposable>` instead of `Task<IDisposable>`, and update usages from `using` to `await using`.

The `NatsSubscriber` is mostly straightforward. I'm not sure of the purpose of the first parameter passed to `Disposable.Create` (it's not part of the Rx `Disposable` or anything else I could find), so I'm just ignoring it:

```
public sealed class NatsSubscriber<TKey, TMessage> : IBusSubscriber<TKey, TMessage>
{
  public async Task<IAsyncDisposable> SubscribeAsync(TKey key, Action<TMessage> callback)
  {
    ...
    return AsyncDisposable.Create(async () =>
    {
      await connection.DisposeAsync();
      observer.OnCompleted();
    });
  }
}
```

The `RedisSubscriber` has synchronous disposal, but my `Disposables` library has a helper for treating sync as async:

```
public sealed class RedisSubscriber<TKey, TMessage> : IBusSubscriber<TKey, TMessage>
{
  public async Task<IAsyncDisposable> SubscribeAsync(TKey key, Action<TMessage> callback)
  {
    ...
    return Disposable.Create(() =>
    {
      subscriber.Unsubscribe(channel);
      observer.OnCompleted();
    }).ToAsyncDisposable();
  }
}
```